# State array changing value depending on where in the code its at

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a small app to learn react basics where I enter in random items and it lists them below. When I press the delete button for that item, it should delete it. The problem is that it is deleting all items that come after it as well.

I tried logging the state of `item` in various spots and realized that inside the function `deleteHandler`, the item state array was only full of the things that came before the item I was trying to delete for some reason. But when I log `item` outside of that function, it properly shows all items. Any ideas what the issue could be?

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
    console.log(item);
    for (const i of item){
        console.log(i.props.id);
    }
    const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);
    const handleNewName = (newName) => {
        console.log("new name has been recieved: "+newName);
        setItem([...item, <ListItem itemName={newName} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} key={itemCount} id={itemCount} />]);
        setItemCount(currentCount => currentCount + 1);
        console.log(itemCount);
        
    }

    const deleteHandler = (key) => {
        setItem(item.filter(i=>i.props.id !== key));
    }
    return (
    <>
        <InputArea handleNewName={handleNewName}/>
        {item}
    </>
    );
}

export default App
```

inputArea.js

```
export default function InputArea(props){
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const handleNewName=props.handleNewName;
  let currName="";
  function snagName(){
    currName = inputValue;
    setInputValue("");
    handleNewName(currName);
  }
  return (
    <>
    <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
    <button onClick={snagName}>Submit</button>
    <br/>
    </>
  );
}
```

listItem.js

```
export default function ListItem (props){
  let currName=props.itemName; 
  let id = props.id;
  const deleteHandler = props.deleteHandler;
  const clickHandler = () => deleteHandler(id);
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>Delete</button><span>Hello, {currName}</span><br/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding

```
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current=item;
```

at the top of my code and changing `deleteHandler` to

`setItem(stateRef.current.filter(i=>i.props.id !== key));`

Is there no better way to solve this? It seems awfully roundabout and complicated for such a simple program compared to vanilla js. Is that just how react is?

EDIT: Found a better way (I think). The problem appears to be solved just by changing from
`setItem(item.filter(i=>i.props.id !== key));`
to
`setItem(currVal => currVal.filter(i=>i.props.id !== key));`